Как сделать, чтобы телеграм бот реагировал в группе на конкретные слова без /
import telebot
import random
bot = telebot.TeleBot('API') 

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) #обработка команды
def main(message):
    photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
    if message.text == 'и' or 'КАРТИНКА'or '' or '' or 'я' or'а' or 'а' or '' or '':
        if photo_random == 1:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, '')
            photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
        elif photo_random == 2:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'eview.jpg')
            photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
        elif photo_random == 3:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'an-com-p-porno-obnazhennie-grudastie-krasotki-72.jpg')
            photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
        elif photo_random == 4:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,'0%B4%D1%8C-4819670.jpeg')
            photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
        elif photo_random == 5:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, '/94029.jpg')
            photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
        elif photo_random == 0:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'LI&type=album')
            photo_random = random.randrange(0, 5)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Хочу чтобы при добавлении бота в общий чат, он реагировал на заданные сообщения, а не на сообщения со слешем. Например:
П1: Привет, что делаешь?
П2: Смотрю на КАРТИНКУ
Бот увидел слово "картинка" и отправил фото.

бот добавлен в группу как администратор?
